# Spring Integration input channel for Service Activator

Tags: spring-integration, channel

I am learning Spring Integration and trying to build small small applications. I have been stuck in my new application. Actually I am trying to get data from 2 different table and compare them. For that i have created 2 different service which individuality are getting data from different different tables.

Now my question.

1. Can i use one gateway and one input channel for calling both the Service Activator which are calling my service methods.If not how shall i approach.
2. How shall i gather both the data for comparison. I mean to say. How shall i send data from 2 different service activator to One end point(say Aggregator) where i can compare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to consider to use a Scatter-Gather component for this kind of tasks: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.1.1.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#scatter-gather

Comment: Document is helpful but i am finding it difficult to implement. If there is any example which can help me in understanding it better, It will help a lot.

Comment: The best sample I can share with you is in our tests: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-core/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/scattergather/config/ScatterGatherTests.java, https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-jmx/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/monitor/ScatterGatherHandlerIntegrationTests.java

Comment: Thanks @Artem It is usefull

Comment: one out of contex question. Can we use one channel for more than 1 Http request. I have 8-10 http request coming in. Is it better to use different channels for all or can reuse the channels.

Comment: If you talk about the *inbound* side (an `HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway`), then yes, you can use the same `reqeustChannel` for all of them. Please, consider to ask such a simple questions on Gitter: https://gitter.im/spring-projects/spring-integration